# Algebraic Integers in a Cyclotomic Field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $p >5$ be a prime number. Prove that every algebraic integer of the $p$th cyclotomic field can be represented as a sum of (finitely many) distinct units of the ring of algebraic integers of the field.

Reference: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/resources.php?c=2&cid=152&year=1977&sid=151602f87027a7ce87d3aa9421a666e9          Question No: 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Miklos Schweitzer is a *very hard* contest.

Anyway, solution for this (and other problems) can be found in the book:

Contests in Higher Mathematics, published by Springer.

Google books has it:

http://books.google.com/books?id=2wwXImJ2HocC

And this particular problem's solution appears here:

http://books.google.com/books?id=2wwXImJ2HocC&pg=PA88

Comment: when I followed your link and looked at the problems in this undergraduate competition, I thought: "What the heck?  I'm a research mathematician and I feel lucky to understand the statements of these problems.  Undergraduates are asked to solve them on the spot?!?"  So I googled and found this, which allowed me to pick up the pieces of my exploded skull and more or less glue them back together: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikl%C3%B3s_Schweitzer_Competition.  (It's a "take-home exam".)

Comment: And open book!  No wonder I had trouble solving Miklos Schweitzer problems on AoPS...

Comment: for some reason I cannot view this book.