# Explicit expressions for the $c_0,\ldots,c_{p-2}\in\Bbb{Z}$ satisfying $(1-\zeta_p)^{p-1}=p\sum_{k=0}^{p-2}c_k\zeta_p^k$.

Tags: commutative-algebra, roots-of-unity, cyclotomic-fields

It is well known that in the cyclotomic ring $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_p]$ one has the equality of ideals
$$(1-\zeta_p)^{p-1}=(p).$$
I'm struggling to find 'manageable' expressions for the associated units
$$\frac{(1-\zeta_p)^{p-1}}{p}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad\frac{p}{(1-\zeta_p)^{p-1}},$$
on the power basis $\zeta_p^0,\ldots,\zeta_p^{p-2}$ of $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_p]$.
One approach I tried uses that
$$(1-\zeta_p)^{p-1}=\prod_{n=1}^{p-1}(1-\zeta_p^n)\frac{1-\zeta_p^n}{1-\zeta_p}=\Phi_p(1)\prod_{n=1}^{p-1}\frac{1-\zeta_p^n}{1-\zeta_p}=p\cdot\prod_{n=1}^{p-1}\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\zeta_p^m,$$
which gives the (to me) unmanageable expression
$$\frac{(1-\zeta_p)^{p-1}}{p}=\prod_{n=1}^{p-1}\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\zeta_p^m.$$
I've written this out explicitly for $p\leq7$, but I don't see a pattern yet. Are there nice expressions for the associated units above?

**EDIT:** I like to clarify that I'm looking for explicit expressions for the coefficients of these units on the standard power basis for $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_p]$. And although the answer by sharding4 below does exactly that, I was hoping for expressions without denominators. That is, expressions from which it is immediately clear that this is an element of $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_p]$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the units of cyclotomic integers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3185/what-are-the-units-of-cyclotomic-integers)

Comment: @Chickenmancer I disagree; I'm asking for the coefficients of very specific units on the standard power basis of $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_p]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly "manageable" expression in terms of the power basis can be obtained simply by applying the binomial theorem to $(1-\zeta_p)^{p-1}$ and using the fact that $\zeta_p^{p-1}=-\zeta_p^{p-2}-\zeta_p^{p-3}-\cdots - \zeta^2-\zeta - 1$.  Then $$
\frac{(1-\zeta_p)^{p-1}}{p}=\sum_{k=1}^{p-2}\frac{(-1)^k\binom{p-1}{k}-1}{p}\zeta_p^{k}
$$

Comment: This seems very nice, but how are the coefficients $\frac{(-1)^k\binom{p-1}{k}-1}{p}$ integers? I was hoping for non-fractional (polynomial?) expressions for the coefficients, which is why I took such a detour in my question. Perhaps I should clarify my question, or make it more specific.

Comment: @user38292 It isn't immediately obvious but $\frac{(-1)^k\binom{p-1}{k}-1}{p}$ is in fact an integer for $1\leq k\leq p-2$

Comment: I know it is, for example by Pascal's rule for binomial coefficients, but I was hoping for expressions from which this is immediately obvious. I will try to work from your answer myself as well, thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Also, is there a similarly nice expression for the inverse?